# Struts 2 and Hibernate login form

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am trying to build a simple login form using struts and hibernate. Index.jsp is the welcome file after successfully logging in user will be redirected to home.jsp. I am using an custome Interceptor so that home.jsp wont be directly accessible without logging in. The problem I am facing is

1. I am getting this exception while running application

   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.
   This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. 
   Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter,
   which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
2. home.jsp is directly accessible without logging in.

Below are the files 
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
        <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
        <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
            <Interceptors>
                <Interceptor name="LoginInterceptor" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.interceptors.LoginInterceptor" />
            </Interceptors>

            <action name="login" class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.action.LoginAction">
                <result name="success" type="chain">wolcomeaction</result>
                <result name="imput">/index.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">/index.jsp</result>
            </action>

            <action name="welcomeaction">
                <interceptor-ref name="LoginInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
                <result name="login">/index.jsp</result>
                <result name="success" >/home.jsp</result>

            </action>
        </package>
</struts>
```

LoginInterceptor.java

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.interceptors;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor{

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> session= ai.getInvocationContext().getSession();
        if(session.get("userObject")==null)
        {
            return Action.LOGIN;
        }
        else
        {
            return Action.SUCCESS;
        }

    }

}
```

LoginAction.java

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities.Users;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.business.UsersDAOImpl;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Users user;
    private Map<String, Object> userSession;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String execute(){
        if(verify())
        {
            return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
        }

        else
        {
            return ActionSupport.LOGIN;
        }

}

    @Override
    public void validate(){
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(getEmail()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(getPassword()))
        {
            addFieldError("Error","oops! something went wrong try again");
        }
    }

    private boolean verify(){
        String email=getEmail();
        String password=getPassword();
        UsersDAOImpl udl=new UsersDAOImpl();
        user = udl.LoginVerify(email, password);
        if(user!=null)
        {
            userSession.put("userObject", user);
            userSession.put("userName", user.getFname()+" "+user.getLname());
            userSession.put("email", user.getEmail());
            userSession.put("userId", user.getUid());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
        userSession=map;
    }


}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form action="login" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <s:label>Email:</s:label>
                <s:textfield name="email"></s:textfield>
                <s:label>Password:</s:label>
                <s:password name="password"></s:password>
                <s:submit name="loginsubmit"></s:submit>
            </fieldset>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDITED: pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.riteshsangwan</groupId>
    <artifactId>ossoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ossoc</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-testing</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>        
            <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
          <type>jar</type>
       </dependency>    

       <dependency>        
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
       </dependency>    



       <dependency>        
            <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.3</version>
       </dependency>                                

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter mapping is a bit incorrect, correct mapping should be :

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Secondly, the interceptor declaration is a bit-faulty (case issues). A sample login interceptor stack can look like :

```
 <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="nlogin" class="interceptors.LoginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="nlogin"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
```

The `default-interceptor-ref` takes care of default interceptor stack that'll be executed for all actions defined in that package.

Thirdly, the code of interceptor always executes & returns the result, without giving the other interceptors, even the action to execute. A sample login interceptor can look like :

```
@Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (ai.getInvocationContext().getSession().get("admin") == null) {
                Object action = ai.getAction();
                if (action instanceof ValidationAware) {
                    ((ValidationAware) action).addActionError("Unauthorized access. Please Login first");
                }
                return "login";
            }
            return ai.invoke();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ai.invoke();
    }
```

Comment: I make the above changes but the problem continues

Comment: I just checked the code of interceptor is incorrect, you're returning from there only, without further execution of the interceptor stack & the action itself.

Comment: @coding_idiot If you noticed the action configuration doesn't have a class, so it seems correct.

Comment: @coding_idiot 
I am not able to view index.jsp I am always getting 1st problem. help me with this..